# How get notification if finder open some folder

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, notifications, finder

I am working on project which mix "Dropbox" and version control. 
My app is daemon which communicate with server (retrieving info about files updates) and injected into Finder code (response for injected code requests about which kind of image show for every file).

I overlaying files icon in finder, so I need to "refresh" files in some folder (check for updates on server) when user open it. But I need to check server updates only when user opened  some folder (user opened "folder1" in finder, I need to check server if there are some changes for files in "folder1"). 
Is it possible to receive some kind of notification if user open some folder in finder? 
I haven't find any kind of this in FSEvent (obviously, because nothing changes in folder).

My App doesn't have any UI, only overlay custom icons in Finder (like Dropbox).

Comment: The question is rather: What are you trying to do? Why do you think you need to know if the user opens a folder in Finder? In case there was a way to get such a notification, how would you react to it?

Comment: In case there was a way to get such a notification, how would you react to it?  - I'll retrieve fresh info about folder content from server

Comment: Okay, and why do you need to retrieve fresh info about that folder if a user opens it in Finder? As you already said in your question, you won't receive FSEvents if the folder hasn't changed, which means you will receive FSEvents in case it did change. Why do you need to retrieve fresh infos about a folder of that you know that it has not changed?

Comment: I need to display out of synch icon if files changed on server. I need to refresh info only for folder user opened (not recursively). Is there any FSEvent for this? As I said I can't find any event if nothing changed in folder.

Comment: How can the icon files be out of sync without anything changing on the server? If the icon files are out of sync, something has changed on the server, hasn't it?

Comment: How can the icon files be out of sync without anything changing on the server? If the icon files are out of sync, something has changed on the server, hasn't it?  FSEvent for track changes on local machine. But if file changed on server I have to display it. I don't have server check based on time interval. I ask server about changes for particular folder right after user open those folder. That's why I need to know when user open some folder.

Comment: 1) Please stop quoting my text, I know what I have said and everyone here can see it, too. 2) Why do you force the user to open a server folder in Finder so that Icons displayed in some other app get updated? Why don't you let the user go to that Folder in your app? I think forcing a user to use another app when he actually wants to use your app is the wrong approach to begin with. Maybe you should give a lot more details about the whole project, like what is the purpose of the app, what is the purpose of these server folders, etc. Do so by editing the question, not by adding more comments.

Comment: Sorry for quoting. Thank you for advice.